# FFmpeg PNG+MP3 = FLV

Tags: ffmpeg, png, mp3, flv, video-encoding

I need to create a FLV video from a MP3 file and a PNG image, and I tried the following ffmpeg command:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i file.png -i file.mp3 -acodec libmp3lame -vcodec flv -y -ac 1 -ab 32000 -ar 22050 file.flv
```

I obtained a FLV video file with the correct audio and the image, but it is not seekable in VLC, so I'm looking where I'm wrong.

Could you help me, please?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why `-vcodec flv`? Nobody uses "FLV / Sorenson Spark / Sorenson H.263" anymore. H.264 video (use `-vcodec libx264`) is almost always a better choice.

Comment: And if you do, add `-pix_fmt yuv420p` to your command.